# Variable selection and adding noise data

Tags: r

Its my first post and english is not my first language so please bear with me.
I have searched the forum about my problem but im still looking forward to the suitable answer.
So here is my problem im trying to use spike and slab package as a variable selection tool for the first time and i have a data set of 1000 examples and 8 variables, but i think i need more variables to evaluate the effectiveness of the package and i dont know how i can add more random variables to my data set.
Is there any command in R that do this ? Can you please help me friends?
I appreciate your inputs

## Thanks.

### the code i've used :

```
diabet=read.csv(data,header=T,sep=",")
diabet
library(spikeslab)
obj <- spikeslab(BS~ . , diabet)
print(obj)
plot(obj)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhJoY.jpg

as you can see all of my variables are included as top vars

Comment: Post code of what you have?

Comment: Please post some code you've tried.

Comment: `noise = matrix(rnorm(nrow(diabet) * number_of_columns_to_add), nrow = nrow(diabet)); new_data = cbind(diabet, noise)`

Comment: #gregor thanx it worked and i added 40 cols but after applying my piece of code to new data output was kinda odd cause it included 3 of noise data and just 2 of my old variables. What do you think of this gregor?